# How to rename temporary text file to master text file and delete privious existed master file

Tags: java, file-handling

this code is inserting updated records into temporary file after inserting will have to rename temporary.txt to master file because it has Updated records .but that time i want to delete privious master text ..How to do? that module for Deposit money.

```
public void insertIntoTempoFile(String uID,String uName,String mobNo,String depoAmt)
{   File f1= new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\BankReport\\temporary.txt");
    File f2= new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\BankReport\\master.txt");

    FileWriter fwTemp = null;
    
try {
    f1.createNewFile();

    
    fwTemp = new FileWriter(f1,true);
        
     fwTemp.write(uID);  
     fwTemp.write("#");
     fwTemp.write(uName);  
     fwTemp.write("#");
     fwTemp.write(mobNo);  
     fwTemp.write("#");
     fwTemp.write(depoAmt);  
     fwTemp.write("\n");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

finally {
    try {
        fwTemp.close();
         
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If you rename a file to a existing path there are two scenarios, 1. Fails because already existing file or 2. Overwrite the existing one. I think you should do this:
1. Write your temporary file (temp1).
2. Rename master to temp (temp2).
3. Rename temp1 to master.
4. Delete temp2 or rollback temp2 to master if fails.

Comment: its doesn't work ,i chaged no.of way but it shouldnt ..

Comment: pleasel suggest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code writes data to `temporary.txt` and if there is no exception, writes renames the file to `master.txt`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    insertIntoTempoFile("123", "Garreth", "321", "345");
}

private static void insertIntoTempoFile(String uID, String uName, String mobNo, String depoAmt) {
    String directory = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\BankReport\\";
    String sourceFilename = "temporary.txt";
    String targetFilename = "master.txt";

    Path sourcePath = Paths.get(directory + sourceFilename);

    String row = uID + "#" + uName + "#" + mobNo + "#" + depoAmt + "\n";

    try {
        Files.write(sourcePath, row.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        renameMasterFileIfExists(directory, sourceFilename, targetFilename);
    }
}

/**
 * Take a look here for more details https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-rename-file-in-java/
 */
private static void renameMasterFileIfExists(String directory, String sourceFilename, String targetFilename) {
    Path source = Paths.get(directory + sourceFilename);
    Path target = Paths.get(directory + targetFilename);

    try {
        Files.move(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```